# unable to list values in LOV from mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql

unable to list the information in LOV list from mysql table . I need to list the categories(catname)  in the dropdown box and also let me know how to select the value(catno) for further action.

```
    <?php
require_once('dbconnect.php');

$selsql="SELECT catno,catname FROM category"; //catno-integer and catname-
varchar
$res=mysqli_query($con,$selsql);
//$r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
if (mysqli_query($con,$selsql)) {
}
else
{
echo "No connection";
die(mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Drop down list </title>
<meta charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport">
</head>
<body>
<select name="categories" 
style="width:250px;"onchange="this.form.submit();">
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)):;?>
<option value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"<?php echo $row[1];?></option>
<?php endwhile;?>
<!---<option value="<?php echo $row[0];?>""<?php echo $row[1];?>"</option>->
<!----$options.='<option value="'.$row[0].'"selected>'.$row[1].'</option>'->

</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
<?php
require_once('dbconnect.php');

$selsql="SELECT catno,catname FROM category";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$selsql);
if ($res == '')
{
    echo "No connection";
    die(mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drop down list </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport">
</head>
<body>
    <select name="categories" style="width:250px;" onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['catno'];?>"><?php echo $row['catname'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: changed. but same issue.

Comment: have you wrapped catno and catname in quotes after using `mysqli_fetch_assoc`? Like this `$row['catno']`

Comment: yes its like that only, Still not working. mysqli_fetch_row is also not taking.

Comment: can you please show me exactly what error you're getting?

Comment: the values are not listing in the LOV. i.e blank list of values

Comment: why you have a `;` after while? `<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)):;?>`

Comment: this one i have changed with <?php 
    foreach($data as $row):
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['catno'];?>"<?php echo $row['catname'];?>      </option>

<?php endforeach;?>                         but still no lov in the dropdown

Comment: you haven't closed the angular bracket `>` of opening `option` tag